# How do I use mssql server service name during accessing database object from sql?

Tags: sql-server-2008

when accessing database objects from other server I use [server].[database name].[schema name].object_name

but if the service name of the mssql database server is different than the default service name (i.e. MSSQLServer2008R2) then how do I access the database object? what would be the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing several different things here.

The *instance* name is the name you provided when you installed SQL Server. If you didn't give an instance name, then you installed a default instance that has no name. See the documentation on instances [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143531%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). You can access a default instance using `ServerName` but to access a named instance you need to use `ServerName\InstanceName`.

Each instance of SQL Server has a Windows *service* that runs it; the name of that service is formed from the instance name by default. These are the services that you see in the Windows Services list or SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Finally, when you use four-part naming to access a database on another server, you define a *linked server name* when you create the linked server. The server name you give does not necessarily have to be the same as the remote server's instance name; it can be anything you like. See the documentation for `sp_addlinkedserver` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Your question seems to be asking, "what is the correct linked server name for a named instance on another server?". Example A in the documentation I linked to for `sp_addlinkedserver` shows how to create a linked server to a SQL Server named instance, I think that may be your real question.